# Strange Issues with datagrid in wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I am new to wpf and working on an accounting application. My problem is so simple yet I am astonished that I can not find a simplistic solution for this, it goes like this:

I have to create a datagrid in which only columns should have visible borders.

I mean it should look something like this:

```
 ____________________
 | col1 | col2| col3|
 |______|_____|_____|
 |   r1 |  r1 |  r1 |
 |   r3 |  r2 |  r2 |
 |      |     |     |
 |      |     |     |
 |      |     |     |
 |      |     |     |
 |______|_____|_____|
```

I can draw a grid without the borders at bottom but the problem is in that if there is only one row in the datagrid the column borders will not go down till the outer border of datagrid I mean if there is only one row that's how my datagrid looks:

```
  ____________________
 | col1 | col2| col3|
 |______|_____|_____|
 |   r1 |  r1 |  r1 |
 |   r3 |  r2 |  r2 |
 |______|_____|_____|
 |                  |
 |                  |
 |                  |
 |__________________|
```

which is simple to understand because there is only one row, but what I want is irrespective of the number of rows there should be lines touching to the bottom border of the datagrid, Is there any simple way tot his??

One more problem with it is I want the first row to be selected and focused whenever the form is loaded but no matter how hard I try...it remains unresolved...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way could be to get the last row of DataGrid using [this](http://techiethings.blogspot.com/2010/05/get-wpf-datagrid-row-and-cell.html) post and set it's height to

`height = DataGridHeight - Height of all rows except last one`

You may also need to subtract value like DataGridHeaderHeight.

About your second problem.. have you tried setting SelectedIndex of DataGrid to 0 inside loaded event of DataGrid?

Comment: It may work but wouldn't it be against the MVVM pattern as we are controlling the visual representation from code behind??....and also it fails when the number of rows is more than the visual area of datagrid height, i.e When there is a scroll bar in datagrid..any other ideas??

Comment: Well first of no it's not against MVVM because we are only playing with Visual Elements in the code behind we are not doing anything related to data or business logic. For the second problem you can check whether the scroll bar exists or not, it it exists you don't need to apply this condition

Comment: Thanks for clearing my doubt about MVVM, but about the scroll bar if it exists and I dont apply the condition, it would be still the same problem once user scrolls down...and one more point wouldnt it look strangfe if user inserts teh data in the last row??...

Comment: Once you are scrolling doesn't this mean that the last row is at end of the DataGrid already? would you need any solution in that case?

Comment: umm yeah I guess you are right  thanx a lot.....about the second one yes I have done that the problem is though it makes my first row selected focus is still outside/on the datagrid, what I want it as soon as datagrid is loaded the first row not only should be selected it should have keyboard as well as logicalfocus...so that user can start editing without pressing ny key or using mouse....